# Prevent nginx from adding extra slashes

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-config

I wanted my nginx configuration to redirect all incomings requests from

`myServer.com/myApplication/doSomething` -> `myServer.com:7080/doSomething`

`myServer.com/myApplication/doSomethingElse` -> `myServer.com:7080/doSomethingElse`

I came up with the following solution after reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-an-http-request-to-another-port) post:

```
location /myApplication{
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7080/;
}
```

No I encounter this weird behavior, that when I test everything locally on the server it seems to work fine, but when I call it from another machine nginx seems to add an extra slash to the path. The curl request I use is this one:

```
curl --location --request POST 'myServer.com/myApplication/doSomething'
```

The error I get from my application has the follwing error message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-07T12:33:41.666+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String \"//\"",
    "path": "//doSomething"
}
```

The error message says, that there is a problem with the extra slashes, but the curl request does not contain double slashes. When testing it locally, where everything works, I use the following request:

```
curl -X POST localhost:7080/doSomething
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I just needed to add a `/` to the end of the location so it would be properly substituted away.

```
location /myApplication/{
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7080/;
}
```